# Gutenberg Editor: dynamically edit slug field based on ACF field

Tags: permalinks, javascript, block-editor, slug

I'm trying to edit the `slug` field on the right panel of Gutenberg editor and edit its content based on a custom field.

I noticed that I can access the field by using this JavaScript to interact with the React Component:

`wp.data.select('core/editor').getEditedPostSlug();`

My question is: How can I edit this field in JavaScript?

There's no `.setEditedPostSlug()` method for this and select the field in normal JS script is impossible because the field's ID is generated each time the panel is opened and if we close the panel, the field disappear from the DOM.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this question: [Gutenberg Editor: dynamicaly change slug field with an ACF field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/405250/gutenberg-editor-dynamicaly-change-slug-field-with-an-acf-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the way to edit the slug's field. Just simply use:

```js
wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').editPost({slug: 'my-slug-value-here'});
```

With an event listener like this, I can dynamically change the slug field based on a custom field:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(() => {

    const acfField = 'field_61f8bacf53dc5';
    const inputShortTitle = document.getElementById('acf-' + acfField);

    const slugify = (str) => {
        return str.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-')
            .replace(/-+/g, '-').replace(/[^\w-]+/g, '');
    }

    const updateSlug = () => {
        wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').editPost({slug: slugify(inputShortTitle.value)});
    }

    if (inputShortTitle !== null) {
        inputShortTitle.addEventListener('input', () => updateSlug());
    }
});
```